# Reading text from a Hidden and Protected Word Document (programatically by using C#)

Tags: c#

I have written an application (MS WORD ADD-IN Application)  which will hide some part of the text (one paragraph) this is done by the following code

```
object start =0;

object end = 0;

Word.Range rng = Doc.Application.ActiveDocument.Range(ref start, ref end);

rng.Text = "sample text To Hide";

rng.Font.Hidden =1;
```

With above code i can able to hide the text (rng.Text). After Hiding i'm protecting the document (which contains both hidden as well as other plain text (unhided) by using

```
Doc.Protect();
```

Now when i want to retrieve the hidden text, I'm using

```
 rng.Font.Hidden =0;
```

but it is throwing exception since document is protected.

Now my question is "*how to retrieve the hidden text after protecting the document is there any way to get the hidden text before unprotecting the document*". Any kind of help is appreciated.

I'm using visual studio C# project for creating Word ADD-IN.  anyone please help me by giving your valuable suggestions.

Comment: What did You tried si far? What is the exact question?

Comment: From your description it is not clear what you are doing. May be post some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Like people are saying, you need to be more explicit in your questions.
If what you need is how to send the password to open the file, the code is something like this (you create the password, and :

```
object passwordd = "pass";
object readOnly = false;
object isVisible = true;
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
string docpath="file path";

Word.Document aDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(ref docPath, ref missing, ref readOnly,
ref missing, ref password, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible,
ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

If it is something else, please be more clearer.